# Short story in Fantasy & Science Fiction in the mid to late 90s about a girl scared to get implant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, brain-implant

I am looking for a short story I read in the magazine *Fantasy and Science Fiction* in the mid-1990s, like '94 or '95 maybe.

The story is about a preteen girl who is afraid to get a communication implant. She is around 12 and her mom tells her to stop being a baby because all of her friends have already gotten the implant. The implant allows people to talk telepathically. The girl went to get the implant but again got scared and didn't get it.

In the end, some kind of system glitch happens and everyone with the implant goes into a coma. The girl is left to take care of the children who were not mentally able to take the implant, people who have a mental disability. I don't remember the author or edition, only that it was in the Fantasy and Science Fiction magazine.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if that will help you improve your question

Comment: This is a `story-identification` question, and the genre tags are only for talking about the genre itself (otherwise everything here would have one of those tags and it would be pretty useless).